# Singularization function for English words in bash

Tags: bash, nlp

Any pointers to a bash function that performs singularization on English words? It does not need to be perfect.

Comment: By words you mean nouns or verbs or both? In the first case you need to remove an 's', in the second case add an 's'...

Comment: I meant any word, including verbs and nouns.

Comment: @bugur, that depends on the context and such a syntactical analysis is the last thing I would expect from `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

Imperfect one would be `${word%s}`.

Comment: :D I was hoping for something a little more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cover both nouns and verbs, and/or the imperfect solutions turn out to be too imperfect then forget Bash and look into tools for *morphological analysis and disambiguation*.